# how to solve gocardless developer key error

Tags: python, gocardless

I am trying to use the gocardless_pro API and I keep getting a key error which am not sure how to resolve.

Below is my code

```
import os
import gocardless_pro

client = gocardless_pro.Client(
    access_token=os.environ['testing123'],
    environment='sandbox'
)
```

Running this code alone throws the below key error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-2b23701d8478> in <module>
      2     # We recommend storing your access token in an
      3     # environment variable for security
----> 4     access_token=os.environ['testing123'],
      5     # Change this to 'live' when you are ready to go live.
      6     environment='sandbox'

~\Anaconda3\lib\os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    676         except KeyError:
    677             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 678             raise KeyError(key) from None
    679         return self.decodevalue(value)
    680 

KeyError: 'testing123'
```

Here is the link am following: https://developer.gocardless.com/getting-started/api/making-your-first-request/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Change the line `access_token=os.environ['sandbox_-VghfQfP7nNxN_arDMfAMKF9qKdyLA05teLqGDky']` to `access_token='sandbox_-VghfQfP7nNxN_arDMfAMKF9qKdyLA05teLqGDky'`
2. Set an environment variable with your token value, then reference that like so:

Do this first from command prompt:

```sh
$ export TOKEN=sandbox_-VghfQfP7nNxN_arDMfAMKF9qKdyLA05teLqGDky
```

Then reference token from Python like so:

```py
import os
import gocardless_pro

client = gocardless_pro.Client(
    access_token = os.environ['TOKEN'],
    environment='sandbox'
)
```

Comment: Happy to help. As a side note, it is usually recommended to avoid hardcoding secrets. Thus, of the two options presented, the preferred option is to use environment variables.